# How to Properly pull data from Excel into Powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint presentation with a slide that has several labels on it.  I need the value of the labels to be pulled from an excel-sheet that is located in the same folder as the powerpoint presentation file.

The code I use to populate the labels so far is this:

```
Public Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
   If Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition = 1 Then
        'load variable values?
        Dim xlApp As Object
        Dim xlWorkBook As Object
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlApp.Visible = False
        Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ActivePresentation.Path & "\QSheet.xlsx", True, False)
        BrownRetail = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1).Range("B3").Value
        lblBrownTruckRetail.Caption = "$" & CCur(BrownRetail)
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Set xlWorkBook = Nothing
   End If
End Sub
```

This works, except it is quite slow loading (10-15 seconds to start the presentation) and the labels show with a white background instead of being transparent. Also, it seems odd to me that the label values stay persistent even in design view.

Is there some better way to pull a value to populate a label from an excel-sheet?

Comment: You might find it faster to load your values from a plain-text file: that way you don't need to load up Excel each time. As for values persisting in Design view: if you programmatically set a label's Caption property then you'd expect it to still be set even after quitting the presentation (ie. there's nothing marking that values as "temporary").

Comment: I dont normally work with PPT, I guess I am looking at it like a program running and then retaining the label values after the program is shut off.  I like the idea of loading from a text file, maybe a csv?

Comment: It's not clear from your code example what sort of object is representated by lblBrownTruckRetail.  I'm guessing it's one of the various controls from the developer tab, which'd account for the white background.  You might instead want to set the text in a standard PowerPoint text box to the BrownRetail value.  I would also declare BrownRetail as a string rather than simply using it; it's also good practice to put Option Explicit at the top of every module to force you to declare your variables.  Seems like a nuisance but can save lots of trouble in the long run.